# VB Script and filename with space

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I wrote a VBS file to open the "6 May" folder with following content

```
path = "F:\Test\2010\May\6 May"
Set Sh = CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")
Sh.Run ""path"",3,True
Set Sh = Nothing
```

However on executing this I am getting following error

---

### Windows Script Host

Script: F:\Sperry\2010\May_06 May\open.vbs
Line:   4
Char:   10
Error:  Expected end of statement
Code:   800A0401
Source:     Microsoft VBScript compilation error

---

### OK

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `""path""` syntax is incorrect. To concatenate strings in VBScript, you need to use the [`&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w.aspx) operator. Also, to specify a quote character as part of the string, you need to double it. So, your script should look like this:

```
path = "F:\Test\2010\May\6 May"
Set Sh = CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")
Sh.Run """" & path & """", 3, True
Set Sh = Nothing
```